# How do you read and write from a specific address of an EEPROM from sysFS

Tags: embedded, storage, sysfs

I have a 24CS02 EEPROM on my I2C bus.  I can successfully read it and have successfully written to the beginning of the EEPROM (ie from /sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0050/eeprom).  I am wondering if/how to read and write a specific address.  I am hoping for something a little more efficient than reading the entire EEPROM, and overwriting the part I want to write and then writing the whole thing back.  Is this possible from sysFS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use dd or write your own program and use the seek function on the file to move to the offset you want to write to.  For example if you wanted to write 64 bytes from input.bin starting from offset 2048 you could do the following...

```
dd if=input.bin of=/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0050/eeprom bs=1 count=64 skip=2048 seek=2048
```

Skip is the offset to start from for the input file and seek is the offset to start at for the output (eeprom).  Count is the number of bytes to write.